# Gridview update not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, datagridview

When i click on EDIT button in Grid, it amke all fields editable and provides two options(Update and Cancel). In this Grid, there are two dropdownlists, 3 calenders and some textboxes. If i click on update then all the textbox values updated in the database, but all other fields(dropdown and calender) values in database is automatically NULL.

Below is the main page GridView code:

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" ForeColor="#333333" width="1000px"
                GridLines="None"  OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" 
                AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
                BorderStyle="Outset" CellSpacing="1" Font-Names="Cambria" 
                Font-Size="Small" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="True" 
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
               >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="case_number" HeaderText="Case Number" 
                        SortExpression="case_number" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="case_name" HeaderText="Case Name" 
                        SortExpression="case_name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Case_Type_Text" HeaderText="Case Type" 
                        SortExpression="Case_Type_Text" />

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Status" SortExpression="Case_Status_Text">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Case_Status_Text" DataValueField="Case_Status_Text" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Case_Status_Text") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Case_Status_Text") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:BoundField DataField="assigned_date" HeaderText="Assigned Date" 
                        SortExpression="assigned_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="assigned_to" HeaderText="Assigned To" 
                        SortExpression="assigned_to" />


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Withdrawn" SortExpression="date_withdrawn">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker5" runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("date_withdrawn", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Delivered" SortExpression="date_delivered">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker7" runat="server" 
                                />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("date_delivered", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QC By" SortExpression="qc_by">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="User_Name" DataValueField="User_Name" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("qc_by") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qc_by") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QC Date" SortExpression="qc_date">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker6" runat="server" 
                                />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qc_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Additional Notes">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("additional_notes") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("additional_notes") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" 
                        CausesValidation="False" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:con %>" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:con.ProviderName %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [View_Intakesheet]" 
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE intakesheet SET case_number = @case_number, case_name=@case_name, Case_Type=@case_type, Case_Status = @case_status, assigned_date = @assigned_date, assigned_to = @assigned_to, date_withdrawn= @date_withdrawn, date_delivered= @date_delivered, qc_by = @qc_by,  qc_date=@qc_date, additional_notes = @additional_notes WHERE (case_number = @case_number)">
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_number"/>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_name" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_type" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_status" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="assigned_date" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="assigned_to" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="date_withdrawn" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="date_delivered" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="qc_by" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="qc_date" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="additional_notes" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Below is the Update event::

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DropDownList ct = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("case_type");
    DropDownList cs = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("case_status");

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE intakesheet SET case_number = @case_number, case_name = @case_name, Case_Type = Case_Type, Case_Status = Case_Status, assigned_date = assigned_date, assigned_to = assigned_to, date_withdrawn= date_withdrawn, date_delivered= date_delivered, qc_by = qc_by,  qc_date=qc_date, additional_notes = additional_notes WHERE (case_number = case_number)", immigration);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    con.Close();

    bind();

}

public void bind()
{

    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from intakesheet", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "intakesheet");
    //GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE intakesheet SET case_number = @case_number, case_name = @case_name, Case_Type = Case_Type, Case_Status = Case_Status, assigned_date = assigned_date, assigned_to = assigned_to, date_withdrawn= date_withdrawn, date_delivered= date_delivered, qc_by = qc_by,  qc_date=qc_date, additional_notes = additional_notes WHERE (case_number = case_number)", immigration);
```

change this line

mainly problem with these

`Case_Type = Case_Type, Case_Status = Case_Status`,  in update query

```
 DropDownList ct = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("case_type");
    DropDownList cs = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("case_status")
```

;

send ct.SelectedIndex.value if want to send ids if you have bind with its value

if you want send selected index
then 
send
 dt.SelectedText

like

```
Case_Type = ct.SelectedItem.Text, Case_Status = cs.SelectedItem.Text
```

check this line

```
   DropDownList cs = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList3")
```

similary give the correct id for case type

in above line you are passing the ids of dropdown, you should send either its selected value of its selected index

changes

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE intakesheet SET case_number = @case_number, case_name = @case_name, Case_Type = Case_Type, Case_Status = Case_Status, assigned_date = assigned_date, assigned_to = assigned_to, date_withdrawn= date_withdrawn, date_delivered= date_delivered, qc_by = qc_by,  qc_date=qc_date, additional_notes = additional_notes WHERE (case_number = case_number)", immigration);

```
cmd.parameters.add("@case_number",sqldbtype.nvarchar).value = case_number // the string variable of case number
```

do similar for others parameters

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do that??

Comment: Is this ok..
        string CaseType = ct.SelectedValue;
        string CaseStatus = cs.SelectedValue;

Comment: I am getting ERROR::  Object reference not set to an instance of an object :: on line :: string CaseType = ct.SelectedValue;

Comment: check, i think the cs and ct is null, its not finding the dropdown

Comment: check the modified answer

Comment: In the UPDATE EVENT code: can you tell me how can i declare all other text fields and calender fields..??

Comment: similarly, we are able to find the dropdown, same way find the textbox and then like string str= ((textbox)row.findcontrol("textboxid")).text.trim()

Comment: Is there any other way except to put all fields of that grid in editable template, to find the ID for the fields?

Comment: There is no need to put the controls in edit template to find the ID of controls, its the row from where we find the controls

Comment: In that case, how we can get the ID of the fields?
I have used :: string case_number = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text.Trim();

::::::::::: But now i am getting error::Must declare the scalar variable "@case_number"

Comment: you wont be able to get the ids, you will be able to find the controls using the id of controls

Comment: I have used ::::   string case_number = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text.Trim(); ::::::::::: But now i am getting error::::    Must declare the scalar variable "@case_number"

Comment: you have to added the parameters bro

Comment: Hey Can you  explain  this line  Case_Type = ct.SelectedText, Case_Status = cs.SelectedText ??? Your answer was not clear . Please put correct code. Because it's over confusing ,so i post a new answer !!

Comment: @RameshRams , the actual synax is DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text, any one in .net he is aware how  to get the selected text, he has alot of problems with code, so give him the hints, if you go through the comments you can check he is able to get, and by the way you if this  case you should modify this answer, rather than posting a new one just because a syntax

Comment: @AnkitGoyal see the answer below i have give one syntax for adding a paramenter

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam :::: How can i use datepicker like dropdownlist :::  DropDownList cs = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList3") ::: Because i have tried datepicker like that but it is not recognizing the syntex..

Comment: Actually you dont need to find the date picker, obviously you will be putting value of date selected in particular textbox, so find that textbox

Comment: and if you want to find just cast is as ajaxcontroltoolkit.calenderextender if you using ajax calender, note : check syntax

Comment: I am up voting your question, you will be then having more than 20 reputation so that we chat in room, here long chat is not permitted

Comment: Ok. how can we go to chat room?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with a GridView that was not updating. Inspection of the e.Newvalues Dictionary in the GridView's RowUpdating event showed that the old values for the record were being sent to the database UPDATE query.  DataKeyNames was not my problem; I had it set correctly. The WHERE clause of my SELECT query referenced a control parameter against a TextBox on my form.  I had inadvertently set EnableViewState for this textbox to "False". Because of this, the GridView was rebinding itself before the UPDATE occurred. Setting EnableViewState on the TextBox to "True" fixed the problem. Here is the code to see the UPDATE parameters:

```
    Protected Sub MyGridView_RowUpdating _
    (sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) _
    Handles MyGridView.RowUpdating

    ' Inspect the parameters being sent to the database for an ASP NET GridView UPDATE.

    Dim I As Integer

    I = 0

    For Each MVO As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry In e.OldValues
        If MVO.Value Is DBNull.Value OrElse MVO.Value Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print(I.ToString + ": " + MVO.Key + " Value:  ")
        Else
            Debug.Print(I.ToString + ": " + MVO.Key + " Value:  " + MVO.Value.ToString)
        End If

        I += 1
    Next MVO

    I = 0
    For Each MVN As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry In e.NewValues
        If MVN.Value Is DBNull.Value OrElse MVN.Value Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print(I.ToString + ": " + MVN.Key + " Value:  ")
        Else
            Debug.Print(I.ToString + ": " + MVN.Key + " Value:  " + MVN.Value.ToString)
        End If
        I += 1
    Next MVN


End Sub
```